# Finding a determinant-function such that the image is an arbitrary scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Generally a determinant function is a function $\delta:V^n\rightarrow F$ where $V$ is a vector space and $F$ is a field such that the map is multilinear and alternating.

We also know that the the the function $\text{det}$ is a determinant-function. Where with $\text{det}$ I mean the "canonical/standard" determinant function over a matrix. We know $\text{det}(E)=1$

I want to show there exists a determinant function $q$ such that for a given scalar $\delta$ and a given basis $X=a_1,\ldots,a_n$ of $V$ we have $q(X)=\delta$

I have tried to show it but all my attempts involved roots and I am trying to avoid this.

Comment: The ideal solution depends on the background from which you want to answer the question.  Your determinant function is an element of $(\wedge^nV)^*$, the dual space to the $n$-fold alternating tensor product of $V$ with itself.  It can be shown that the dimension of $\wedge^k V$ is $\binom{n}{k}$, so $(\wedge^nV)^*$ has dimension $1$.  Therefore $q$ is “determined” by its value on an ordered basis.

Comment: However, you can also be explicit and express $q$ in terms of a change-of-basis matrix between $X$ and $E$.

Comment: I admit I didn't understand the question and what you mean by *determinant function*, i.e. which properties such a function should have. E.g. the *canonical* one has the property that $det(XY) = det(X) det(Y)$, but if we choose the trivial basis such that $X = I$ (or $E$ in your notation) this property only holds for $\delta = 1$ (or $\delta = 0$), not for any given scalar in $F$. Can you point to the exact definition of this kind of *generic determinant function*?

Comment: In the case that $\dim V = n$, all such determinant functions will be multiples of each other. So, take any existing determinant function, and just scale it to what you want. If $\dim V < n$, then the only such functions that exist are zero. If $\dim V > n$, there might be many interesting functions, which are not multiples of each other.